# Getting Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to do a simple import of data from cvs as a dataframe with the help of pandas in python. But i am getting Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

code used :

```
import pandas
df=pandas.read_csv("myfile.csv")
print(df)
```

Do you have any idea why I am getting this issue . Please let me know if you guys need any more details from me

Note : Sorry I corrected the typo (Its the typo while asking the question)
I typed just `import numpy` line even for that i am getting 
[image]

Comment: That’s the only error you’re getting? It looks like there’s a typo in your code.

Comment: You should learn to read the full error message, not just the last part. It would have shown you that "`module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_cvs'`". You basically have a typo for, "cvs" should be "csv".

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to import a Comma-Separated Values (*.csv) file? If so, you need to change `pandas.read_cvs("myfile.cvs")` to `pandas.read_csv("myfile.cvs")` (and you may need to change your file from `myfile.cvs` to `myfile.csv`).

The documentation for `read_csv` [can be found here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Your code would look something like:

```
import pandas
df=pandas.read_csv("myfile.csv")
print(df)
```